# How to check if a distribution is subgaussian using a finite sample?

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing

Let $X_1, X_2... X_n$ be a iid sample of size $n$ from some distribution. How can I check if the distribution of these $X_i$ is subgaussian? Is there some statistical test I can apply?

My thought is that a distribution is subgaussian if it's tails are bounded by some gaussian, but in practice I can always find some gaussian distribution whose tails dominate those of my finite sample of size $n$.

Comment: You cannot be sure, but the lack of even moderate outliers is suggestive, as is for example a `qqnorm` plot in R where the top and bottom ends are flatter than the middle part of the graph

Comment: Are you familiar with any work on designing statistical tests for this?

Comment: @Thomas Winckelman This question is underspecified. All data will be subgaussian, as any bounded random variable is subgaussian. On the other hand, the subgaussian parameter can be so large that there is poor bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I agree certainly. But honestly it's just not clear to me why this should make statistical tests impossible. For instance, all data is bounded, as you say, but nevertheless there exist statistical tests for whether that data comes from the (unbounded) Gaussian distribution itself.

Comment: That said, I agree that the problem probably needs to be refined. Can you also suggest refinements? What refinements of the question have been considered already? If not a single refined version of this question has been considered in the literature, why not?

Comment: I guess you are right @ThomasWinckelman , my objections are perhaps too rigid. A natural test is to standardize the data to have unit empirical variance and look at the empirical even moments and check that they are of the order $(2k)!!$ This approach is interesting because it allows flexibility with how many empirical moments you check, which of course, affects the size and power. If you simulate some poisson data, it should, at first glance, seem like a good test?